# Return a List of distinct values from DataGridView

Tags: c#

As the topic says: Is there a way to return a list of distinct values from a certain Column of a DataGridView?

Comment: You shouldn't try getting values from a view. Instead, read them from the model.

Comment: Yes, but I likely work more with the view instead of the datasource.

Comment: I think this link is for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899568/count-distinct-values-of-a-column-in-datagridview-using-linq-in-net

Comment: This link was for counting, i want to have a list of distinct strings

Comment: @TaW Nice thats what I was looking for

Comment: yes, Linq is soo nice :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should do what you asked for:

```
var vv = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                           .Select(x => x.Cells[yourColumn].Value.ToString())
                           .Distinct()
                           .ToList();
```

Note that the simple version above assumes that there are only valid values. If you also may have new rows or empty cells you may want to expanded it like this:

```
var vv = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                           .Where(x => !x.IsNewRow)                   // either..
                           .Where(x => x.Cells[column].Value != null) //..or or both
                           .Select(x => x.Cells[column].Value.ToString())
                           .Distinct()
                           .ToList();
```

Comment: Is it possible to make this a "oneliner"? like to store the values direct into a List<string> ?

Comment: ??? This really is a one liner and it does create a List<string>. I inserted the line breaks only for better readability.

Comment: Oh.. my lack of knowledge is disturbing... As I have learned c# on my own I was not confirm that this var is usable as a datasource.

Comment: Indeed it is just a shorthand. Hover over the word var and you see to what type the compiler will evalute it. You can just as well write `List<string> vv = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(x => x.Cells[0].Tag.ToString()).Distinct().ToList();` - Not noticing Linq is a mistake I made myself for  (ahem) years ;-)
`

Comment: @josef_skywalker:  I just used the code myself for a data entry autocompletion cell and had to expand a little.